# EventWaiter doesn`t working correctly JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to create an EventWaiter when someone click on select menu with this code below, but it doesn't seems to work. Event waiter does not respond to pressing, but only sends a message after the time has elapsed.

```
   waiter.waitForEvent(
       SelectMenuInteractionEvent.class,
           e -> !e.getSelectMenu().isDisabled(),
           e -> {
                 channel.sendMessage("yes").queue();
                },
           20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, () -> {
                 channel.sendMessage("No").queue();
                }
           );
    });
```

Comment: The `if(!equals(e.getComponentId()))` doesn't make any sense, you need to compare it to an id. And `isAcknowledged` will always be false if you never reply.

Comment: The code you have now looks correct. If it still doesn't work the problem must be elsewhere. Are you sure the the event of clicking on the menu is sent to this waiter?

Comment: @Deltharis No, I don't have anything in the onSelectMenuInteraction method that is responsible for clicking on the menu. Or am I confusing something

Comment: The code you're showing in your question only defines what the listener will do when it receives events, and it looks correct. Which means the other possible reason why it's not writing YES is that it's not receiving any events - in which case it's impossible to tell what's wrong as it's not in the code in your question. I don't know discord-jda, can't help more than that without some concrete code to look at.